# Fiddler filter tabs never works

Tags: fiddler

Im running the latest version of Fidder and cannot get the filters to work. On the filters tab I have choosen the following:

[image]

So as you can see, i just want to see traffic from independent.ie. I have choosen "Show only the following hosts" and entered www.independent.ie. I have also selected "Show only if URL contains" and input "independent". But no matter what options I choose, all traffic is always shown on the left hand panel. When i choose Actions > Run Filterset Now, nothing happens.

How dan i possibly get Fiddler to respect filters?

Comment: Neat! I don't see any obvious reason for this, but your window is such that some of the normal clues are missing. Please send us email using Help > Send Feedback, along with a `SAZ` file (File > Save > Session Archive) of some traffic that should be hidden but isn't.

Comment: I completely uninstalled fiddler then re-installed and now its working